# Qt QML Settings are not saved/applied

Tags: qt, qml, settings

I have simply copied this example from the docs, adjusting the import version number to the newest ones (but I tried with both for same result).

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import Qt.labs.settings 1.1

Window {
    id: window

    width: 800
    height: 600

    Settings {
        property alias x: window.x
        property alias y: window.y
        property alias width: window.width
        property alias height: window.height
    }
}
```

As opposed to advertised, the window geometry was not saved after I closed and reopened the window. In fact, it now doesn't show the window at all? (I tried re-running qmake and cleaning all)

I also get this warning every time I run the project in Qt Creator, regardless of whether I use Settings or not:

```
17:01:02: Starting C:...debug\untitled.exe...
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
qrc:/main.qml:10:5: QML Settings: Failed to initialize QSettings instance. Status code is: 1
qrc:/main.qml:10:5: QML Settings: The following application identifiers have not been set: QVector("organizationName", "organizationDomain")
```

1) Is the warning related to the issue?

2) How do I remove the warning?

3) How do I get the settings to be applied as advertised?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

...Turns out I had to keep reading the docs to the end.

1) Warning is related to the issue.

2) Per the docs, add this at the beginning of the main in main.cpp

```
app.setOrganizationName("Some Company");
app.setOrganizationDomain("somecompany.com");
app.setApplicationName("Amazing Application");
```

3) Now works as advertised.

Comment: It is always useful to read the documentation, or the warnings you are getting and just want to get rid of...

Comment: I had actually googled the warnings before, and had not found any information. Hopefully this so question might help in the future.